# React hooks async problems: map is executing before data is returned - solutions?

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks

In the code below, you can see that I'm mapping over data returned from an axios `GET` request. I'm then passing this data through a filter, and setting it to state (under the variable `gig`).

I'm then wanting to map over the data held in `gig` - only problem is that when I try, I get an error say that  `TypeError: gig.map is not a function`, and `gig` console logs to undefined.
However, when  `gig` is console logged inside the useEffect method, it returns the data I want.

So I'm guessing that what is happening is that setState is aysnc, and the `gig.map` function is being reached before the `gig` has been set to `filteredGigs`.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Here's the full code:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import { auth } from 'firebase/app'

const UniqueVenueListing = (props) => {

const [gig, setGig] = useState([])
const authUserId =  props.userDetails.uid
    
useEffect(()=>{
    axios.get("https://us-central1-gig-fort.cloudfunctions.net/api/getGigListings")
    .then(res => {
        let filteredGigs = res.data
        .filter(gig => {
            return gig.user !== authUserId
        })
        setGig({gig: filteredGigs})
        console.log(gig)
    })
},[])

useEffect(() => {
    console.log(gig)
}, [gig])

    return(
        
        <div>
          {
              gig.map(gigs => {
                  return gigs.user
              })
          } 
        </div>
    )
}

export default UniqueVenueListing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

You change the state shape. Initial shape of `gig` state is an empty array(`[]`), but in the effect you store an object with an array under key `gig` (`{ gig: filteredGigs }`). Additionally since state updates are asynchronous, the console.log after `setGig` will only log the *current* state, not the one just enqueued.

## Solution

Just save the filtered gig array into state. This will keep the `gig` state an array and later in the return `gig.map(...` will work as expected.

```
useEffect(()=>{
  axios.get("https://us-central1-gig-fort.cloudfunctions.net/api/getGigListings")
  .then(res => {
    const filteredGigs = res.data.filter(gig => {
      return gig.user !== authUserId
    })
    setGig(filteredGigs); // <-- store the array in state
  })
},[])
```